# Issues in before_destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried add before_destroy for model but I have some problems and I cannot understand where is the problem.Destroy of the model `ReturnCode` is calling from other model `Command`.In `Command` has column for `ReturnCode` `return_code_id` how can I fix the problem.I'm using Rails 2.3.12

`models/Command`

```
after_save :delete_old_private_return_code

def delete_old_private_return_code
if !self.return_code_id_was.nil? && self.return_code_id_was != self.return_code_id
  return_code = ReturnCode.find(self.return_code_id_was)
  if !return_code.nil? && return_code.private?
    return_code.set_audit_key(self.command_set.audit_key, self.command_set.audit_area)
    return_code.return_code_texts.each do|text_param|
      text_param.set_audit_key(self.command_set.audit_key, self.command_set.audit_area)
    end
    return_code.destroy
  end
end
```

end

`models/ReturnCode`

```
  attr_protected :created_at, :updated_at, :shipped_data

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  before_validation :strip_spaces
  has_many :commands
  has_many :return_code_texts, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :return_code_texts, :allow_destroy => true
  before_save :sort_action_list
  before_save :set_audit_parent
  before_update :audit_line_number
  before_destroy :set_audit_parent
  before_destroy :audit_line_number


 has_one    :record_level_security, :as => 'securable', :dependent => :destroy

  validates_presence_of      :name, :if => Proc.new{|return_code| return_code.shared?}
  validates_length_of        :name, :maximum => 20, :allow_nil => true, :if => Proc.new{|return_code| return_code.shared?}
  validates_uniqueness_of    :name, :case_sensitive => false, :if => Proc.new{|return_code| return_code.shared?}
  validates_presence_of      :description, :if => Proc.new{|return_code| return_code.shared?}
  validates_length_of        :description, :maximum => 50, :allow_nil => true, :if => Proc.new{|return_code| return_code.shared?}
  validate :validate_values_matching
  validate :validate_action_list
  validate :validate_text_list
  validate :cannot_change_standard_name


 def audit_line_number
    command = Command.find_by_return_code_id(id)
    Audit.add_audit_changes({"line_number" => [command.line_number, command.line_number]})
  end
```

`Error`

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `line_number' for nil:NilClass):
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:238:in `method_missing'
  app/models/return_code.rb:288:in `audit_line_number'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  app/models/command.rb:289:in `delete_old_private_return_code'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:2120:in `update'
  org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2093:in `send'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
  org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
```

Comment: please add more info on command.rb.
How is `delete_old_private_return_code` invoked?
Your problem is that `Command.find_by_return_code_id(id)` is `nil`.

Comment: Yeah I know but at time of call before_destroy should be return_code_id in command because it does not deleted yet.

Comment: are you sure that `Command.find_by_return_code_id(id)` is not nil

Comment: Yeah I checked it in db.

Comment: no no , at the time of function invoking it is nil , actually the id which is getting passed is nil . So , `Command.find_by_return_code_id(nil)` is nil

Comment: can you try `Command.find_by_return_code_id(self.id)` instead

Comment: I'have checked it, but id has value it isn't nil it's like `1035`.I think that maybe it's blocked because rails want delete it. I've tried find `Command` by other parameter also and I received result not nil.

Comment: It's not in the code you posted, but is the save in Command altering its return_code_id?